# Is there Firefox 4 addon like ImgLikeOpera (which works for FF 3.6)?

Tags: images, firefox-extensions, firefox

In Firefox 3.6 ImgLikeOpera does what I want: I can selectively download images I want to view, have some sites that show images by default, show only cached images etc. The only issue is slight incompatibility with AutoPager.

Hovewer, in Firefox 4 I don't see any flexible image visibility manager: ImgLikeOpera 0.6.20 works bad (Ctrl+Rightclick fails, Alt+M fails, no toolbar item etc.) and ImageBlock 2.1 is too simple - I don't see image placeholders and can't show them individually?

Are there some another extensions that I should try?

Comment: Have you tried [ImgLikeOpera 0.6.21](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/) yet?

Comment: Please repost as an answer, 0.6.21 works well.

Comment: Okay, I did that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an update to [ImgLikeOpera, version 0.6.21](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/)  Please try that.